# What is the point of Modules in NestJs?

Tags: nestjs

I am learning NestJs. Previously I have written Express app in an object oriented way, with dependency injection for services into controllers.

While I easily understand how NestJs can accomplish the same with @Injectable(), I am not sure what is the use of Modules.

In my OOP Express app, I would register my routes directly with something like "this.app.use(this.router)", and each feature has its own route. So I am not even using modules at all.

On the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules), it says: "We want to emphasize that modules are strongly recommended as an effective way to organize your components. Thus, for most applications, the resulting architecture will employ multiple modules, each encapsulating a closely related set of capabilities."

So is it just an optional way for us to better organize, or am I missing something fundamental?

Thanks!

Comment: better organization, improves reusability and testing, I'd say

Comment: Organisation, scoping, reusability (libraries/monorepos), easier testing, etc...